# SendGrid gives fatal error

Tags: php, composer-php, lamp, sendgrid

I've put in the code according to the documentation the only thing I did was add templating. Can anyone see what's wrong?

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    date_default_timezone_set('EST');
    # Include the API
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    require 'lib/SendGrid.php';
    require 'html2text.php';
    # Instantiate the client.
    $sendgrid = new SendGrid('...', '...', array("turn_off_ssl_verification" => true));
    $html = $_POST["message"];
    $text = convert_html_to_text($html);
    $date = date('l, F jS ');
    # Make the call to the client.
    $email = new SendGrid\Email();
    $email
        ->addTo('...')
       # ->addTo('...') uncomment on final script
        ->setFrom('...')
        ->setSubject('New reminder for ' . $date)
        ->setText($text)
        ->setHtml($html)
        ->addFilter("templates", "enabled", 1)
        ->addFilter("templates", "template_id", "a874a34a-a9b7-460b-a5ae-7226e68da0f1")
    ;
    print '<h1>Sent successfully</h1>';
    ?>
```

---

**Result:**

```
Fatal error: Class 'SendGrid\Email' not found in /home/[...]/public_html/[...]/sendgrid.php on line 29
```

Comment: Can you check echo file_exists( 'vendor/autoload.php' ); ? Also see if your composer if correctly setup.

Comment: Yes it is. I'm migrating from a different solution that also used composer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `SendGrid\Email` class isn't being autoloaded properly. To fix it manually you can add `require 'lib/SendGrid/Email.php';`.

Comment: Now that I've added everything. Script runs fine but I'm still not receiving the email.

Comment: You need to call the function to send the email `$sendgrid->send($email);`. Find the full usage [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php#usage)

Comment: Hi there, I have downloaded the API files from the git repository (https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) and I could not find the Email.php file anywhere, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have php 5.8 OR 7.0. I had the same problem, did the following to get it to work:

1. Updated composer.json

```html
{
    "require": {
        "sendgrid/sendgrid": "~5.1"
    }
}
```

2. php composer.phar update
3. php composer.phar install

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not using Composer, simply download and install the latest packaged release of the library as a zip.

Then require the library from package:

`require("path/to/sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");`